How do I merge and coalesce several dataframes in R?
I have several datasets that are the results of long to wide transformations. Example data:
data1 <- data.frame(
                   x1 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),          # Create example data frame
                   x2 = c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                   x3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA),
                   y = 11:16,
                   z = 6:1)

data2 <- data.frame(
                   x1 = c(NA, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA),          # Create example data frame
                   x2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA),
                   x4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2),
                   y = 11:16,
                   z = 6:1)
               
data3 <- data.frame(
                    x2 = c(3, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA),          # Create example data frame
                    x3 = c(NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                    x5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3),
                    y = 11:16,
                    z = 6:1)



All datasets have the same number of rows.
Some columns are identical in all datasets, like y and z in the example.
Other columns are only present in some datasets. Some are found in
multiple datasets (as x1, x2, and x3 here), other ones are only found
once (as x4 and x5 here). These columns have many NA and a few valid
numeric values.

I want to merge the datasets, obtaining the following:
 datafull
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  y z
1  1  3 NA NA NA 11 6
2 NA  1  3 NA NA 12 5
3  2  3 NA NA NA 13 4
4  2 NA  1 NA NA 14 3
5 NA  2  1 NA  3 15 2
6 NA NA NA  2  3 16 1

All columns should be present and any valid value present in any dataset should be included in the dedicated column to replace NA in other datasets (e.g., see how x1 and x2).
I tried with
datasetlist <- list(data1, data2, data3)
datafull <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all.y=TRUE), datasetlist)  

but what I get is
datafull
  x2  y z x3 x1 x4 x5
1  3 11 6 NA NA NA NA
2  3 13 4 NA NA NA NA
3 NA 12 5  3 NA NA NA
4 NA 14 3 NA  2 NA NA
5 NA 15 2 NA NA NA  3
6 NA 16 1 NA NA  2  3

It seems like in the iterative merge done by Reduce, values from the new datasets completely replace old values, also when the new value is a NA.
Any idea on how to avoid this?

Create a list L of all data frames and get a vector of all names in them, xn.  Then create L2 which is like L except every component data frame has all columns in xn such that previously missing columns are filled with NA.  Finally apply coalesce from dplyr.
library(dplyr)

L <- list(data1, data2, data3)
xn <- sort(Reduce(union, lapply(L, names)))
L2 <- lapply(L, \(x) replace(x, xn[! xn %in% names(x)], NA)[xn])
co <- function(x) do.call("coalesce", lapply(L2, "[[", x))
data.frame(Map(co, xn))

giving
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  y z
1  1  3 NA NA NA 11 6
2 NA  1  3 NA NA 12 5
3  2  3 NA NA NA 13 4
4  2 NA  1 NA NA 14 3
5 NA  2  1 NA  3 15 2
6 NA NA NA  2  3 16 1


Excellent! This is actually more similar to my attempted solution! I am glad to see that there was a solution using reduce and coalesce!

Write a function to accomplish the same
patch_all <- function(x){
  if (is.data.frame(x)) return(x)
  nms_x <- names(x[[1]])
  if (length(x) == 1 & is.data.frame(x[[1]]))
    return(x[[1]][, order(nms_x)])
  nms_y <- names(x[[2]])
  nms_all <- intersect(nms_x, nms_y)
  x[[2]] <- tibble::rowid_to_column(x[[1]][nms_all])|>
    dplyr::rows_patch(tibble::rowid_to_column(x[[2]][nms_all]), 'rowid') |>
    cbind(x[[1]][setdiff(nms_x, nms_y)],
          x[[2]][setdiff(nms_y, nms_x)])  |>
    select(-rowid)
  x[[1]] <- NULL
  Recall(x)
}


patch_all(lst(data1, data2, data3))
  x1 x2 x3 x4 x5  y z
1  1  3 NA NA NA 11 6
2 NA  1  3 NA NA 12 5
3  2  3 NA NA NA 13 4
4  2 NA  1 NA NA 14 3
5 NA  2  1 NA  3 15 2
6 NA NA NA  2  3 16 1


Neat, it works! I am now going to try it on my real data which is of course more complex. Since the function is quite complex (for my standards at least) would you mind explaining what it does step by step? It would be extremely useful for me.

@Silvia The idea is to patch the rows that contain NA with the values that are non-NA. But row_patch only works with data that have similar columns. Thus first you subset the similr columns from first and second data, by intersecting the names, patch the rows and bind the unselected columns. Repeat the process

Excellent, it works also on my real data! Small question: what does the function do if two valid (nonNA) values are provided for the same column-row in two different datasets? It is an unlikely situation, but I would like to know what the function does. Ideally it should retain the first valid value. BTW I am surprised that there is no built-in function for this.

@Silvia it will maintain the first value. If the solution helps, consider upvoting/accepting it
